# Disable Click to Use Abilities (Hotkeys only)

Tags: dota-2

Is there a way to disable clicking to activate abilities?  I'm asking because I had a near loss the other night by accidentally "regular" clicking Tidehunter's ult when I meant to alt-click it.  Is there a setting or a console command or something I could use to allow abilities to only be activated by hotkeys, but still alt-clickable?

Comment: Don't take my word 100% for it but as far as I'm aware of there is none. I always have a mini heart attack when I alt+clik a big ulti to show its ready by fear of activing it.

Comment: Same, but i suppose missclicks are part of the game as well...

Comment: I would like this.  My alt-clicking goes back to the time when abilities had it but items didn't....that time I alt-clicked my refresher orb was the worst feeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to disable that even with console commands.

Comment: This is sad...  I really need the ability to do this to get my bro to stop using the click instead of hotkeys.  It's really impairing his ability to play and doesn't seem to be able to break the habit.

Comment: put a cover over his HUD? lol